# Encoding Messed Up File

Tags: input-encodings

I wish I knew how this happened. 
Using Texshop, under Preferences, encoding is UTF-8. 
File contains the following lines in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

When I compiled the file, I got all sorts of instances like the following:

```
ÃćÂĂÂIJBritish
```

When I went to Macros=>Encoding it seems the file is encoded in MacOsRoman. 
I changed that setting to UTF8 (I don't know if this overrides TexShop's global preferences) but I'm still getting these wild characters.

-How do I get rid of them?

The file otherwise compiles properly.

Edit: I did convert the file to UTF8. 
I used Textwrangler to "Zap Gremlins" and most of these disappeared. However, I have to go back and add back in some high-ASCII characters that ere deleted, like é.

But wait! Now when compiling I get the following error:

```
Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:éMa not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

????

I used the utf8x package instead of utf8, and added the following to the beginning of the file:

```
    % !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
```

which was a suggestion by user27221 in a related question.

I'd still like to know how to get rid of these without resorting to an obscure command (Zep Gremlins) in a specialized program that I may not always have access to.

Comment: Probably the file was initially encoded in MacOS Roman. Try to convert it to UTF8 before compiling.

Comment: If your file is encoded in MacOsRoman you need to first convert it to utf8 before invoking inputenc with the utf8 setting.

Comment: Could possibly be that you used to typeset using `XeLaTeX` and now the program is set to typeset in `PdfLaTex` or simular.

Comment: @runartrollet pdfLaTeX is fine with UTF-8 encoding since that option is given to `inputenc`.